# Android, Room "не пишет" в базу данных

Tags: android, android-room

Делаю приложение, основной контент которого находится в SQLite базе. Викторина, в которой предлагается угадать животное.

Начал изучать Room. Всё работает, информация сохраняется и извлекается из db в рантайме(вижу через логи и Toast). Но когда я открываю саму db(физически) в браузере (DB Browser), то вижу там пустоту. Ни таблиц, ничего. А должны быть мои записи.

**Что я хочу сделать**: открыть только что установленное приложение, добавить в db несколько записей, закрыть приложение, скачать созданную db с устройства на PC и открыть её в браузере, чтобы увидеть её структуру.

Пошагово что сделано и где затык:

Рутанул эмулятор.

Определил путь создаваемой Room базы через:

`Timber.d(getDatabasePath(AnimalDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).getPath());`

Получил:

`/data/user/0/com.example.animalslibrary/databases/AnimalDB`

Удалил приложение. Удалил руками вообще весь пакет `com.example.animalslibrary`.

Устанавливаю приложение.

Приложение открыто, ни одной записи не добавлено(запись добавляется руками по кнопке). По указанному  выше пути ничего не создалось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю запись по кнопке. Создаются файлы с моей базой(?) и ещё чем - то непонятным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Продолжаю добавлять записи кнопкой. Моя база `AnimalBD` не меняет размера, зато третий файл жиреет с ошеломительной скоростью(скрин после добавления пяти записей):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Закрываю приложение. Скачиваю `AnimalBD`, открываю - пустота, чистый лист. Даже таблиц нет.

Запускаю приложение ещё раз. Пробую достать запись из базы - достаётся.

Что я делаю не так вообще? Реально ли достать базу? И если нет, то что мне делать если я хочу чтобы у пользователя уже была заполненная база на момент первого запуска приложения? Не буду же я кодом добавлять уйму строк. В комментариях посоветовали подменять создаваемую `Room` базу на свою при первом запуске - но для этого мне ведь нужно понять как устроено то что `Room` создаёт, чтобы создать аналог.

Код. Не уверен что он тут вообще нужен, т.к всё работает. Но пусть будет. Не кидайтесь камнями за перегруженную архитектуру, познаю MVC.

**Activity**

```
  HomeModel homeModel = new HomeModel(Room.databaseBuilder(this,
                AnimalDatabase.class, AnimalDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build());
  HomePresenter presenter = new HomePresenter(homeModel);
  presenter.attachView(this);

  findViewById(R.id.add_animal_button).setOnClickListener(v -> presenter.buttonClicked());
  findViewById(R.id.show_animal_button).setOnClickListener(v -> presenter.button1Clicked());
  Timber.d(getDatabasePath(AnimalDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
```

**HomePresenter**

```
public class HomePresenter {

    private HomeActivity view;
    private HomeModel model;

    public HomePresenter(HomeModel homeModel) {
        this.model = homeModel;
    }

    public void attachView(HomeActivity activity) {
        this.view = activity;
    }

    public void detachView() {
        this.view = null;
    }


    public void viewIsReady() {
    }

    public void buttonClicked(){
        model.addAnimal();
        Toast.makeText(view,"ADDED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void button1Clicked(){
        Animal addedAnimal = model.getAnimalById(1);
        Toast.makeText(view,addedAnimal.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**HomeModel**

```
public class HomeModel {
    private AnimalDatabase animalDB;

    public HomeModel(AnimalDatabase animalDB) {
        this.animalDB = animalDB;
    }

    public void addAnimal() {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setName("TIGER");
        animalDB.daoAccess().insertAnimal(animal);
    }

    public Animal getAnimalById(int id) {
        return animalDB.daoAccess().getAnimalById(id);
    }

    public void initDB(){}
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
public interface DAO {
@Insert
void insertAnimal(Animal animal);

@Insert
void insertAnimals(List<Animal> animalList);

@Query("SELECT*FROM animals WHERE animal_id =:animalId")
Animal getAnimalById(int animalId);

@Update
void updateAnimal(Animal animal);

@Delete
void deleteAnimal(Animal animal);
```

}

**AnimalDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = {Animal.class, AnimalPack.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
public abstract class AnimalDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract DAO daoAccess();

    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "AnimalDB";
    public static String DATABASE_NAME_WITH_PREFICS = "AnimalDB.db";
    public static String TABLE_ANIMALS_NAME = "animals";
    public static String TABLE_PACKS_NAME = "packs";

}
```

**Animal**

```
@Entity(tableName = "animals")
public class Animal implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "animal_id")
private int animalId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "animal_type")
private int type;

@ColumnInfo(name = "animal_name")
private String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "animal_hints")
private String hints;

@ColumnInfo(name = "animal_opened_hints")
private int hintsOpened;

@ColumnInfo(name = "animal_hints_total")
private int hintsTotal;

@ColumnInfo(name = "animal_pack_id")
private int packId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "animal_answer_image")
private String answerImagePath;

public Animal() {
}

   //Тьма геттеров и сеттеров 
   //+ пустой конструктор 
   //+ конструктор, содержащий все поля
   }
```

Comment: database = Room.databaseBuilder(this,
                AppDatabase.class, "database.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .build();

Comment: woesss, добавил для вас правку в ответ. Романыч, моё приложение ничего не знает про класс AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory(), и он не гуглится. Что это? В остальном код не отличается от того что у меня уже есть.

Comment: Посмотрел правку - Если коротко, то у вас база данных не копируется а создается чистая.  Я пытался как то переделать свои каракули под такие же нужды но в итоге оставил как было на SQLiteAsset Helper. Room, как я понял, пока до этого не дошла. Вам  нужно при первом запуске копировать базу из ресурсов а далее не создавать новую а читать уже готовую.

Comment: Романыч, погуглив глубже я тоже пришёл к похожему решению, просто запихнуть базу с контентом в `assets` и копировать её в "исходный" каталог при первом запуске. Только мне для начала нужно сделать или получить "образ" моей базы, хотя бы пустую "болванку" которую я мог бы в `assets` положить. Вот в чём фокус, а для этого мне нужно понять что именно генерирует мне Room, чтобы сделать подобное. Я конечно начну пробовать методом тыка, с простыми классами я мб справлюсь и угадаю как таблица выглядит, а вот с листами скорее всего нет, разве что если повезёт...

Answer (score 1):

Дополнительные файлы - это файлы журнала `SQLite`. Они нужны для обеспечения быстродействия при многопоточном доступе и целостности данных при сбоях. Данные из журнала переносятся в базу при накоплении какого-то количества транзакций и при штатном закрытии соединения с базой (чего вы судя по всему не делаете).

Просмотрщики баз данных должны знать эти файлы и что с ними делать, поэтому Вы можете скопировать все три в одну папку и открыв файл базы увидеть свои записи.

Answer (score 0):

> Реально ли достать базу?

Базу данных можно вытащить с устройства и без всякого рута, для этого надо в студии открыть файловый менеджер и подключить телефон с установленным на него апк. Можно и эмулятор, но я работаю с устройством. Справа снизу `Device File Explorer`.
Сама база будет находиться в папке `data/data/имя пакета/databases/имя базы данных`
Так ее можно достать посмотреть.

Конкретно в вашем случае я не вижу смысла использовать Room, хотя смысл всетаки есть, но: 
Можно создать готовую базу, я использую `DB BROWSER for SQLITE`

Ну и при старте приложения просто скопировать ее из папки `ASSETS` а далее уже проверить на наличие и прочитать самой `ROOM`.
Вот здесь [давали хороший ответ как скопировать и прочитать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572375/8211160) базу ручками.
Ну а далее имея базу просто работать с ней.