# В каком редакторе открыть БД SQLite созданную в room

Tags: android, sqlite, room

Как известно, room является ORM обёрткой над SQLite. Но, открыть БД созданную в room в редакторе (использую SQLite Studio) не получается.

Точнее файл открывается, только таблиц в нём не видно. Хотя в приложении данные добавляются и выводятся на экран.

Делаю по руководству из [этой статьи](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/dagger-2/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html).

[image: Скриншот]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если у вас рядом с файлом бд есть ещё один или два с таким же именем, то скопируйте их все в одно место и открывайте файл бд. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951939/11515

Comment: @woesss, спасибо! Помогло! Оформите пожалуйста Ваш комментарий как ответ чтобы я мог добавить Вам репутацию.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я использовал ValentinaStudio. Очень удобная программа во всех отношениях: имеется возможность редактировать (добавлять, удалять, изменять) ячейки в таблицах, подключить бд можно удобно. [Вот](https://www.valentina-db.com/ru/all-downloads/vstudio/current) ссылка на их сайт для загрузки, надеюсь поможет.

Так же есть и другой вариант - открыть через стороннюю утилиту Android Debug Database. [Вот](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) ссылка на гитхаб, тоже вроде ничего.

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429372/view-contents-of-database-created-with-room-persistence-library) есть вопрос по данной тематике, может поможет. Удачи :)

Comment: За полезные ссылки спасибо. Но проблема была решена при помощи совета от woess.